# JQuery .find with multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this problem with Jquery items[c] is well defined as HTMLElement but when I use .find with more than one selector I get this error:

```
TypeError: X[g].exec is not a function
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js
```

when i checked some watches i got what is in the image below:

`$(items[c]).find('.received')` works fine and returns some elements as there is elements with that class

`$(items[c]).find('.receive')` works fine too and returns zero elements as there is no elements with that class.

but `$(items[c]).find('.received.unseen')` returns undefined and bugs. so what is happening here?

[image]

**EDIT**: here is what is inside items[c], from the debugger firefox
[image]

**EDIT:** here is the function where i have the bug and i switched to jquery 2.1.1:

```
function updateUnseenBell(){
    var m;
    for (var c in items)
        if (items.hasOwnProperty(c) && (m = items[c].gEbCN("chat-partner-tab")[0])) {
        if($(items[c]).find('.received.unseen:not(.shown)').length > 0){
            if (!(m.l2_newMsgBell)) {
                m.appendChild(m.l2_newMsgBell = newMsgBell.cloneNode());
                playSound("message");
            }
        } else if (m.l2_newMsgBell) {
            m.removeChild(m.l2_newMsgBell);
            delete m.l2_newMsgBell;
        }
    }
}
```

and i reduced it to this minimum for debug but still get the same error:

```
function updateUnseenBell(){
    for (var c in items) {
        if (items.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
            if ($(items[c]).find('.received.unseen:not(.shown)').length > 0) {
                alert(1);
            } else {
                alert(2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add html mark up? is element `.received` and `.unseen` same or child?if child just add space between them

Comment: further to @guradio - if you are targetting multple selectors (ie not child) you need a comma between them ... $(items[c]).find('.received, .unseen')....

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (besides, I'm pretty sure .find handles compound selectors just fine).

Comment: What is items[c]? what does it contains? Please log it and post it

Comment: @guradio thank you. no they are classes for same element so there should not be a space in fact my finale purpose is to use this $(items[c]).find('.received.unseen:not(.shown)'). to select all elements in items[c] that have received and unseen classes but not shown. but it does not work even with just ('.received.unseen')

Comment: Can you share the markup of the `.unseen.received` element

Comment: @progrAmmar: What difference would it make? (In case you're unaware, elements with multiple classes are marked up with space-separated class names.)

Comment: @Abhishek Dhanraj Shahdeo  and progrAmmar i Edited the question by adding the Dom of items[c]

Comment: If you want to actually get to the bottom of this, I suggest trying to reproduce this in an isolated test case on a new page or on jsfiddle.net. jQuery has never had any problems with .find as far as I know, and I really don't see why it would be returning undefined in this situation.

Comment: You say you get `undefined` with `.unseen.received`, What happens if you try `.message.unseen.recieved`. Whenever I use a multi-class selector I always include the full class definition.

Comment: @progrAmmar i ve tried different configs but all not working. and i fact it's just for debug purpose that i use only .message.unseen notmally after i need to use this selector '.received.unseen:not(.shown)', that is for element not having class shown, this class is added after by javascript but i can't come there still because this bug comes as i load the page

Comment: @BoltClock yea i'm trying that there but being a novice with fiddle using i get an other error ReferenceError: $ is not defined on [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vv6ckvvd/)

Comment: @fekiri malek: You'll need to include your version of jQuery. You can do this by clicking the cog next to where it says JavaScript, and looking under Frameworks & Extensions.

Comment: @BoltClock i didn't get how you do it, but using $.fn.jquery i get 1.11.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
$(items[c]).find('.message.received.unseen')
```

and that should work.

One other way to solve this will be

```
$(items[c]).find(".received").find(".unseen").find(":not(.sh‌​own)")
```

Its not an elegant approach but works too.

Comment: i  have tried that but it does not work. item misses an s btw.

Comment: yes thank you i managed to get the full functionality (with :not(.show)) too on the site, and it works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u8k6m5hf/) .. so I don't know what i'm missing in my code. i posted the function above in the edit.

Comment: inside the`if (items.hasOwnProperty(c)) {` if you do console.log(items[c]) do you get what you attached as an image. Also what does `items` contain.

Comment: yes i get the right object. i even added var a = items[c]; which i use after: ($(a).find(".received.unseen:not(.shown)"); but still the same.

Comment: try `var a = $(items[c]).not(":visible");` and then `$(a).find(".received.unseen:not(.shown)"`. It also works in the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/y8tfeuy1/3/

Comment: well that did not work , but u put me on a way that  fixed it not the best way but as it works i keep it for now : $(items[c]).find(".received").find(".unseen").find(":not(.shown)")

Answer (score 0):

Another approach you can use:

```
$(items[c]).find(".received, .unseen, :not(.sh‌​own)");
```